# Facebook gives the error message "Please enter your profile name using only letters" when I enter my name in Unicode

Tags: facebook, unicode

I have already entered my name in Russian language characters in Facebook. Recently I tried entering my name in Facebook in Sinhala Unicode characters. But it keeps me giving the error message "Please enter your profile name only using letters." How can I resolve this error and change my name to appear in Sinhala Unicode.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to use mobile keyword. The same issue happened to me in another language, but I used Android default keyboard and the issue solved.